# Parse Javascript keys: readonly access

Tags: parse-platform

I have an iOS app which writes the the Parse datastore. I also have a webpage which i would like to have read-only access to that same data. I've read that this is possible, but cannot find the place in the data browser where this can be set. It'd be ideal to have readonly access for the web client to all classes but one (which will just log the visit). Is that possible?

Comment: Can you tell us a  little bit more about the technology? How are you writing the Web page? My first suggestion is to make the UI elements in the Web page read-only.

Comment: The web page access is all via the Javascript SDK. The answer below is  just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with Roles, simply assign all validated users that login through the iOS app to a role, e.g. "Registered".

Now on each class, set the permissions to prevent Create/Update/Delete except for the "Registered" role.

The web site by default will not be logged in, so will not have a user/roles so will be denied Create/Update/Delete rights.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for this. Clarifies the purpose of roles for me.